# OWIN Cookie Authentication - Equivalent to FormsAuthentication.CookieName?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, owin

I am using the new ASP.NET Identity 2 stuff with an OWIN app. My code looks similar to this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
    CookieDomain = "mysite.local",
    CookieName = "MySite.SSO",
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)
});
```

When I was working with FormsAuthentication before, if I wanted to retrieve the cookie's name or domain, I would do something like:

```
FormsAuthentication.CookieName

FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain
```

etc.

What is the equivalent to this with how I have my app configured? I really don't want to have to set this via an `Web.config` and retrieve it that way.

Comment: Why would you need to retrieve the cookie name after you have set it?  There's nothing you can do with the cookie, since it's encrypted.

Comment: If I need to get the auth cookie's name and domain to inject it into an API call.